# How do I reference a certain structure

Tags: solidity

Here are my declarations and code:

```
struct Key
{
    bytes32 blindedKey;
    uint deposit;
    address player;
    bool revealed;
}
mapping(address => Key[]) public keys;

function seating(bytes32 _blindedKey)
    onlyBefore(seatingEnd)
    {
    //each player gives hash verifies key later
    keys[msg.sender].push(Key({
        blindedKey: _blindedKey,
        deposit: msg.value,
        player: msg.sender,
        revealed: false
    }));
```

The function `seating` has more to it as well.  I am trying now to call a specific entry from another function. I'd like it to be, for example, the second msg.sender's address (player).  So I am trying something like `keys[2].player` which is seemingly wrong but might give an example of what I am looking for.

Typically I pull the information up like this: `var key = keys[msg.sender][0];`

And can use: `key.player` but how do I specify the 2nd key.player etc.

Thanks!

Comment: I deleted this because I realized there might be different solutions but I think I actually need help.  the `keys[msg.sender].push(Key` is a relic from the blind auction example, but I leave it in because it may become useful as the contract evolves.  It allows for the same player to make multiple entries-it's purpose was to allow each player to input false entries with the real ones. 

I will have each player only able to make 1 entry, and so there should be an array of sorts mapping their keys to positions in Key[] but I only get errors when I try things like Key[i]

Comment: Also I think I might be able to use and array here and I'm not sure what is better.  I can create an array that anytime a player successfully enters a choice through  `keys` I can push an entry into the array.  This just means I'll have update the array in other functions in case a player leaves the game. Not confident on the syntax but ill play around with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var key = Key(_blindedKey, msg.value, msg.sender, false);
keys[msg.sender] = key;
```

You can also save some space by not keeping `msg.sender` in `Key` as it is already the map key.